# accepting Uri between 2 numbers

Tags: https, webserver, esp-idf

I'm working on the ESP-idf via Visual Studio Code. Currently I'm working on a Webserver implementation and i would like to accept the following url:

IPADDRESS/command/on/5(number between 1 and 32)

The easiest(but not very efficient) solution would be, to initialize every single uri like this

```
static const httpd_uri_t postCommandOn = {
    .uri       = "/command/on/1",
    .method    = HTTP_POST,
    .handler   = on_command_handler

};
static const httpd_uri_t postCommandOn = {
    .uri       = "/command/on/2",
    .method    = HTTP_POST,
    .handler   = on_command_handler

};
```

etc..

But shouldn't there be an easier method?
Thanks in advance!

greetings

Edit:
Well I don't know how it happened but my complete project is gone now.

I try to redo my steps but facing a new problem which I'm pretty sure didn't exist the last time.

When i try to add this line:

```
    conf.uri_match_fn = httpd_uri_match_wildcard;
```

i get the following Error message:

> error: 'httpd_ssl_config_t' {aka 'struct httpd_ssl_config'} has no member named 'uri_to_match'
> conf.uri_to_match = httpd_uri_match_wildcard;

I dont know why it appears all of the sudden, but I don't really know what i did different to the last time i inserted this line.

my main.c file now looks like this:

```
   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/

#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <esp_event.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <esp_system.h>
#include <nvs_flash.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_eth.h"
#include "protocol_examples_common.h"

#include <esp_https_server.h>

/* A simple example that demonstrates how to create GET and POST
 * handlers and start an HTTPS server.
*/

static const char *TAG = "example";


/* An HTTP GET handler */
static esp_err_t root_get_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
    httpd_resp_send(req, "<h1>Hello Secure World!</h1>", HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);

    return ESP_OK;
}

static esp_err_t status_get_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
    httpd_resp_send(req, "<h1>Hello Secure World!</h1>", HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);

    return ESP_OK;

}

static esp_err_t command_on_post_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
    httpd_resp_send(req, "<h1>Hello Secure World!</h1>", HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);

    return ESP_OK;

}

static esp_err_t command_off_post_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
    httpd_resp_send(req, "<h1>Hello Secure World!</h1>", HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);

    return ESP_OK;

}

static const httpd_uri_t getStatus = {
    .uri       = "/status",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = status_get_handler
};

static const httpd_uri_t postCommandOn = {
    .uri       = "/command/on/*",
    .method    = HTTP_POST,
    .handler   = command_on_post_handler
};

static const httpd_uri_t postCommandOff = {
    .uri       = "/command/off/*",
    .method    = HTTP_POST,
    .handler   = command_off_post_handler
};

static const httpd_uri_t root = {
    .uri       = "/",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = root_get_handler
};


static httpd_handle_t start_webserver(void)
{
    httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

    // Start the httpd server
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting server");

    httpd_ssl_config_t conf = HTTPD_SSL_CONFIG_DEFAULT();

    extern const unsigned char cacert_pem_start[] asm("_binary_cacert_pem_start");
    extern const unsigned char cacert_pem_end[]   asm("_binary_cacert_pem_end");
    conf.cacert_pem = cacert_pem_start;
    conf.cacert_len = cacert_pem_end - cacert_pem_start;

    extern const unsigned char prvtkey_pem_start[] asm("_binary_prvtkey_pem_start");
    extern const unsigned char prvtkey_pem_end[]   asm("_binary_prvtkey_pem_end");
    conf.prvtkey_pem = prvtkey_pem_start;
    conf.prvtkey_len = prvtkey_pem_end - prvtkey_pem_start;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////this line causes the problem///////////////////
    conf.uri_match_fn = httpd_uri_match_wildcard;

    esp_err_t ret = httpd_ssl_start(&server, &conf);
    if (ESP_OK != ret) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Error starting server!");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Set URI handlers
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Registering URI handlers");
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &root);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &getStatus);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &postCommandOff);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &postCommandOn);
    return server;
}

static void stop_webserver(httpd_handle_t server)
{
    // Stop the httpd server
    httpd_ssl_stop(server);
}

static void disconnect_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                               int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    httpd_handle_t* server = (httpd_handle_t*) arg;
    if (*server) {
        stop_webserver(*server);
        *server = NULL;
    }
}

static void connect_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                            int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    httpd_handle_t* server = (httpd_handle_t*) arg;
    if (*server == NULL) {
        *server = start_webserver();
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    static httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

    /* Register event handlers to start server when Wi-Fi or Ethernet is connected,
     * and stop server when disconnection happens.
     */

#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_WIFI
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &connect_handler, &server));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(WIFI_EVENT, WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED, &disconnect_handler, &server));
#endif // CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_WIFI
#ifdef CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_ETHERNET
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP, &connect_handler, &server));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(ETH_EVENT, ETHERNET_EVENT_DISCONNECTED, &disconnect_handler, &server));
#endif // CONFIG_EXAMPLE_CONNECT_ETHERNET

    /* This helper function configures Wi-Fi or Ethernet, as selected in menuconfig.
     * Read "Establishing Wi-Fi or Ethernet Connection" section in
     * examples/protocols/README.md for more information about this function.
     */
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(example_connect());
}
```

EDIT2:

I tried the following:
in the header esp_https_server.h conf is defined as the following =

```
    .httpd = {                                    \
        .task_priority      = tskIDLE_PRIORITY+5, \
        .stack_size         = 10240,              \
        .core_id            = tskNO_AFFINITY,     \
        .server_port        = 0,                  \
        .ctrl_port          = 32768,              \
        .max_open_sockets   = 4,                  \
        .max_uri_handlers   = 8,                  \
        .max_resp_headers   = 8,                  \
        .backlog_conn       = 5,                  \
        .lru_purge_enable   = true,               \
        .recv_wait_timeout  = 5,                  \
        .send_wait_timeout  = 5,                  \
        .global_user_ctx = NULL,                  \
        .global_user_ctx_free_fn = NULL,          \
        .global_transport_ctx = NULL,             \
        .global_transport_ctx_free_fn = NULL,     \
        .open_fn = NULL,                          \
        .close_fn = NULL,                         \
        .uri_match_fn = NULL                      \ //this is the part which is "no member"
    },                                            \
    .cacert_pem = NULL,                           \
    .cacert_len = 0,                              \
    .client_verify_cert_pem = NULL,               \
    .client_verify_cert_len = 0,                  \
    .prvtkey_pem = NULL,                          \
    .prvtkey_len = 0,                             \
    .transport_mode = HTTPD_SSL_TRANSPORT_SECURE, \
    .port_secure = 443,                           \
    .port_insecure = 80,                          \
}
```

you can clearly see, that .uri_match_fn is set NULL(so it is a Member of that struct). If I set .uri_match_fn = httpd_uri_match_wildcard  \ within the header it does work, but i dont want to change the default setting function. I could add another function which implement a uri wildcard, but i think the problem is somewhere else.

someone might have an Idea why it is like that?

Comment: if the URL router doesn't support regular expressions or wildcards (`[2-8]`) you have to implement it in the handler and route `/command/on` and return `404` if an illegal URL

Comment: well i think regular expressions or wildcards aren't supported.

Do you mean with implement it in the handler, that i should parse an incoming illegal uri and route in case its in the format i want?

Comment: if the uri match is a prefix-match (they don't tell in the doc, try it for uri="/command/on/"), in the handler check if number after `/on/` is valid, if not set respond to `404` and exit

Comment: i think i start to understand your approach. 

But if I add a Number after "/on/" (/on/6 for example) i wont be able to access my handler, since I get the response "url not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a search I found an example that shows how it is used:

You have to set the URI matcher to a wild card match.

```
config.uri_match_fn = httpd_uri_match_wildcard;

static esp_err_t on_command_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
    // req->uri is character array with request uri
    // find the number after /on/ and validate
    // and call httpd_resp_send_404(req)
    return ESP_OK;
}

static const httpd_uri_t postCommandOn = {
    .uri       = "/command/on/*",
    .method    = HTTP_POST,
    .handler   = on_command_handler
};

httpd_register_uri_handler(server_handle, &postCommandOn);
```

Comment: ahhh. that's how i slide into the command/on/ handler. Ok now i got it. I think I should be fine from now on.

Thansk!!

Comment: @Dansen If you have a bit time to spare you can write an URI matcher that supports regular expressions, or somebody already has done this

Comment: as soon as i finish my project, i might be looking to do that. I'm kind of curious to get deeper into the esp idf.

Answer (score 1):

The ISP IDF HTTP server supports [custom URI matchers](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_http_server.html#_CPPv4N12httpd_config12uri_match_fnE), where you can create your own logic for matching the incoming request URIs or use [basic wildcard expressions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_http_server.html#_CPPv424httpd_uri_match_wildcardPKcPKc6size_t). I don't have time to dig into the API documentation for producing sample code, but it looks fairly simple.

Comment: how to use `httpd_uri_match_func_t` from the config is not very clear, the text is very vague. The OP has no use for the `*,?` wildcards, they don't support character classes `[]`

Comment: @Tarmo oh ok that helped me alot! Now i accept every uri with command/on/(whatever i want), now i want to filter that stuff. Sadly I cant add the function httpd_uri_match_wildcard in here, due to characterlimit. 

Im kinda new to all that stuff and I'm not sure which part I should edit in the function. You might have some recommendation?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1168ccc98953c3d517f973e24eb1d3ac

https://gyazo.com/ea46f326a7194c125feb173648a8bf41

There's a screenshot. Not sure if you can really use ist. But yeah... it might help

Comment: @rioV8 - embedded systems usually avoid regex implementations due to resource constraints. For matching really simple patters such as this one (numbers 1-32) you can get away with basic string tokenization and a string-to-int conversion.